# Typo3 News Extension - Global News Link Custom per Partner

Tags: typo3

I have the following problem. We have stored several websites for our partners in a Typo3 installation.

We have set up the site so that we bring global news for each customer to their website. If I now create a global message, it appears on the customer's website. Now we would like to place a separate link in the news for each customer. But apparently this is not possible.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Thank you so much!

---

We use: 
typo3 9.5.14
Extension: News System (news)

Comment: Maybe try it with categories? Make categories for news and per customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, whether I understand you correctly.

You can easily use different templates for each customer by changing the paths to the template files in Typoscript for each websites:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.100 = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/News/Customer1/Templates/
        partialRootPaths.100 = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/News/Customer1/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths.100 = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/News/Customer1/Layouts/
    }
}
```

Now you are able to set different links for each website.

---

Another way is to add a Typoscript variable in the settings section of the ext:news typoscript like this:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
        pageLinkUid = 123
    }
}
```

And add the following link into your fluid template:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.pageLinkUid}">page link</f:link.page>
```

The link of the page can be changed with typoscript for each customer.